# My database has been deleted suddenly on the server how to recover it?

Tags: sql-server, recovery

I'm running an application on windows server that connects to a SQL Server database.

Today, when I opened SQL Server Management Studio, I was surprised the database is not in the list of the databases!

I don't know what's the reason. I searched in the server files but I can't find the database and also in the recycle bin.

I put my database in `C:\db\myWeb.mdf` and suddenly it's been removed!

I used stealer phoenix to find the database files deleted on disk but unfortunately I didn't find the db then I tried to add new database with the same name of the deleted db but SQL Server Management Studio said that the database `MyWeb` already exists! That means it's somewhere on the server but I couldn't find it...

Can anyone tell me how to recover the database?

Comment: If you query sys.databases does the database show up in the results?

Comment: @Shawn yes, it is. it's states is RECOVERY_PENDING !

Comment: Have you tried restarting SQL Server service?

Comment: @JChao how can i do it ?

Comment: Start > Run > services.msc

Find SQL Server for your instance, right click, and restart.

Comment: @JChao I tried it but it didn't work .

Comment: If you run the following, what is the error message? Make sure you put your db name. ALTER DATABASE yourDBName SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
Go
ALTER DATABASE yourDBName SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
Go

Comment: this error message :- Unable to open the physical file "D:\db\MyWeb.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path specified.)".
File activation failure. The physical file name "D:\db\MyWeb_log.ldf" may be incorrect.
Msg 5181, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Could not restart database "MyWeb". Reverting to the previous status.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Answer (score 2):

Before restoring from the latest full database backup, you can try Paul Randal's advise - set the database to the EMERGENCY mode and use a login that is a member of the sysadmin SQL Server role to access it. Keep in mind that you will be able only to read the data, as the database will be in the read-only mode.

[Search Engine Q&A #4: Using EMERGENCY mode to access a RECOVERY PENDING or SUSPECT database](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-4-using-emergency-mode-to-access-a-recovery-pending-or-suspect-database/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment that states the database is in "[RECOVERY_PENDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190442.aspx)" state I would read up on what that means via BOL:

> SQL Server has encountered a resource-related error during recovery. The database is not damaged, but files may be missing or system resource limitations may be preventing it from starting. The database is unavailable. Additional action by the user is required to resolve the error and let the recovery process be completed.

Based on that I would run this query against sys.master_files to see what the physical locations are supposed to be for the data and log file:

```
SELECT type_desc, name, physical_name
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('myWeb')
```

You could also review the ERRORLOG for your instance and likely find an error message regarding not being able to find the specific database file.

Comment: this is the result of the command :- ROWS
ROWS
MyWeb
D:\db\MyWeb.mdf
LOG
MyWeb_log
D:\db\MyWeb_log.ldf .. and review the errorlog but didn't find the error msg .

Comment: If the files do not exist in those locations and someone deleted them, then your only option is to restore from your latest database backup.